# Using a value in an array to build a table

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an array built to where I have all the columns I need to build a table. However, I am having trouble splitting up this array to match the according values.

In order to build this array, I am extracting the data from this table as seen in sheet2 labeled "Current Drawing Text"

[image]

Next, I am trying to build a new table based off of the data in sheet2 onto sheet sheet3 (labeled "Wire Checker"), this time using the cables to match which drawing number that they are on. This table currently looks something like this:

[image]

I have the array broken up by cable name. I just am unsure on how I would be performing the matches from the cables to the drawing number. I tried using formulas to "test", but without any luck. This is the code that I have tried so far:

```
    Sub Searchalltest()
    Dim WireCheckerWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DrawingLastRow As Long
    Dim CableLastRow As Long
    
    Dim DrawingandCableRange As Range
    
    Dim CurrentDrawingTextWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim DrawingTableArray
    Dim DrawingNumber As Long
    Dim CableNumber
    
    Dim ArrayStart
    
    Set WireCheckerWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Wire Checker")
    
    'Temporary Varaiables
    Dim Row As Long
    Row = 20
    Dim Column_D As Integer
    Column_D = 4
    
    'End of Temporary variables
    
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary    
    
    Set CurrentDrawingTextWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Drawing Text")
    
    DrawingLastRow = CurrentDrawingTextWorksheet.Range("C" & CurrentDrawingTextWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row to be calculated for every drawing the entry
    DrawingTableArray = CurrentDrawingTextWorksheet.Range("C20:G" & DrawingLastRow).Value
    
    For DrawingNumber = 1 To UBound(DrawingTableArray)                 'iterate between the array rows number:
       ArrayStart = Split(DrawingTableArray(DrawingNumber, 5), vbLf)           'split the cells content on the line separator
       For Each CableNumber In ArrayStart                     'iterate between the splited array elements:
           If Not dict.Exists(CableNumber) Then        'put the array elements in a dictionary (as unique keys)
               dict.Add CableNumber, DrawingTableArray(DrawingNumber, 1)            'the item is the value in array col 1 (Group 1, 2, 3...)
           Else
               dict(CableNumber) = dict(CableNumber) & "|" & DrawingTableArray(DrawingNumber, 1) 'add to the key value the other Groups, separated by "|"
           End If
       Next CableNumber
    Next DrawingNumber
   
   Dim ArrayFinal
   
   For Each CableNumber In dict
     
   

    With Worksheets("Wire Checker")
    
        Debug.Print CableNumber
        .Cells(Row, Column_D).Value = CableNumber
        
        Row = Row + 1
        
    End With

   Next
   
   'Now let's sort the cables
   Dim WireCheckerWorksheetCableLastRow As Long
   
   WireCheckerWorksheetCableLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Column_D).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("A20:D" & WireCheckerWorksheetCableLastRow).Sort key1:=Range("D20:D" & WireCheckerWorksheetCableLastRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
   
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to simplify your question. As it now appears, there's a daunting amount of information to try to sift through. Matching values in an array should be pretty basic, but I reading through your question to find that is a bit challenging.

Comment: You are using your code to explain your logic while simultaneously asking for help to build your code. In Excel this results in a circular reference that can't be resolved. I think you have a list of drawings to make cables and you want a list of cables from which to read off the applicable drawing. For example, cable12 of Class A-Circuit 6 needs drawing 14 but Cable 12 of Class 68 needs Drawing 19.  I'm not sure that VBA would necessarily beat lookup functions but either way, in your sample data Drawing 16 also matches the description. So, what's the logic of the list you want to create?